# Find Id of clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to get the id of clicked button since i have 4-5 buttons on my form.

```
    <button type="submit" style="height: 30px" id="btnHelp" name="btnHelp" onclick="ShowHelp(2);return false;">Help</button>

    <button type="button" style="height: 30px" id="btnClose" name="btnClose" onclick="Close();return false;">Close</button>

    <button type="button" style="height: 30px" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" onclick="Save();return false;">Close</button>

...............................
```

Whichever may be the button click, I just want to get id of that button.

```
$(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        alert(id);
})
```

Also with

```
$("input").click(function (event) {
        var urlid = $(this).attr('id')
        alert(urlid);
    })
```

but i am getting the alert as undefined.

How can i get id of button clicked?

Please help me.

Comment: try to remove onclick function from button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

[:button Selector](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/)

> Selects all button elements and elements of type button.

```
$(":button").click(function (event) {
    var urlid = this.id;
    alert(urlid);
});
```

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3GL76/)</kbd>

---

**Problem**

`$("input")` --> selects elements with tag `input` eg. `<input type="text"/>` but not `<button>` tag .

Comment: @AngryTiger change your selector to `:button`

Answer (score 2):

very simply:

```
$("input").click(function (event) {
        var urlid = this.id;
        alert(urlid);
    })
```

for button:

```
  $("button").click(function (event) {
            var urlid = this.id;
            alert(urlid);
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try use `event` passed as argument into any event handler instead of `this` for `event.target` is referring to element actually triggering your handler (being clicked) and `event.delegateTarget` being element handler has been attached to initially. In both cases you might have to use `$()` for using jQuery or simply stick with accessing `.id` in either case.

In your case this would be

```
$("input").click(function (event) {
    var urlid = $(event.delegateTarget).attr('id');
    alert(urlid);
});
```

to ensure handler is always accessing that  it has been attached to, here.

Except for this quite simple scenario relying on `this` is sometimes trickier than using provided arguments.

**EDIT :** However, your case seems to be related to issues encountered by Tusha Gupta, for sure. Your buttons aren't "inputs" so that handlers are never attached, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to replace `this` with the event triggerer.

```
var urlid = $(event.target).attr("id");
```

Also, probably your `onclick` function is preventing your script to be executed, because it's handling the click event, not letting your function do it.

Answer (score 2):

I ditched the `onclick` attributes of buttons you have, and hooked click events to `button` rather than `input`, and it worked. So check whether you are connecting to the right element.
See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez52S/).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
jQuery(":button").click(function (event) {
        var urlid = $(this).attr('id')
        alert(urlid);
    })
</script>
```

Try this its work

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {

       $("button").click(function () {

        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```