# jQuery + Rails: How to get id of button user clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have spent hours trying to resolve this problem and reviewing other similar StackOverflow questions [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262201/find-id-of-clicked-button) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961934/get-id-of-button-user-just-clicked), but none seem to have an answer to my problem..

I can't get past this error: `ReferenceError: id is not defined`. Alert does not show too.

```
  $("button.btn-tag-cat").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(id);
    id.find('span').show();
    }, function(){
    id.find('span').hide();
  });
```

I have tried the following ways to using the id variable but none work.

```
$(id).find('span').show();
$("#" + id).find('span').show();
```

However, **when i remove the chunk of code below the alert, the alert pops up with the correct id belonging to the button.**

```
  $("button.btn-tag-cat").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(id);
  });
```

**View partial: 
Button id references a ruby local variable** `id="<%= name %>"`

```
  <% q.categories_name_in.each do |name|  %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-tag-cat" id="<%= name %>"><%= name %><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, the error is chaining functions in the click listener.

In order to get the id attribute, you can use the jQuery `attr` function, like:

```
$("button.btn-tag-cat").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
  $('#' + id).find('span').show();
});
```

```js
$("button.btn-tag-cat").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
  $('#' + id).find('span').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn-tag-cat" id="hallo">Press</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, in your code I will beautify it to see your mistake:

```
$("button.btn-tag-cat").click(
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(id);
    id.find('span').show();
  },

  function() {
    id.find('span').hide();
  }
);
```

notice the second function has

```
  function() {
    id.find('span').hide(); // right here
  }
```

but the id is not defined yet

try

```
  function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id'); // this first
    id.find('span').hide();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear response, however, I am now getting this error: TypeError: id.find is not a function

Comment: Use `$(id)` instead id.

Comment: The ID is a string. use `$('#' + id).find(...)`